# unable to pass associative hp array to js function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am trying to pass associative ophp array to javascript function but it is giving me this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Here is my php code

```
      foreach ($staff->roles as $role) {

                    $actionRoles .= $role->name . ',';
                    array_push($selected_roles,['id'=>$role->id,'name'=>$role->name]);
                }

                $tableAction = '
                <div class="menu-item px-3">
                    <a onclick="editStaff(this,"'.json_encode($selected_roles).'")" >
                        Edit
                    </a>
                </div>
   
            ';
```

you can see I am passing array to js function but when I click on it give me error

How I can pass this array from here and how I can receive array from js function ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
foreach ($staff->roles as $role) {
$actionRoles .= $role->name . ',';
array_push($selected_roles,['id'=>$role->id,'name'=>$role->name]);}$tableAction = '<div class="menu-item px-3">
<a onclick="editStaff(this,'.json_encode($selected_roles).')">
    Edit
</a></div>';
```

Comment: i think you just removed double qoutes? i have tried this

Comment: Yes didn't work?

Comment: no that didint work

Comment: I think you should try 1st remove $tableAction Remove then run it
and after u got an error then the error might be in your foreach loop.